# Fitting controls on iPhone screen app when converting from iPad app

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, screen, infinite-scroll

This might be a question specific to my app.I have an iPad app functional. I am converting it to iPhone app. So on one of my iPad screens i have 40-50 controls (labels, textfields,buttons,etc). Now can i achieve something like that on my iPhone also. Screen for iPhone is small and i can barely put 20 controls on one screen. Can i have a long vertical scroll view to put all my controls on one screen. I mean user can scroll down and down and have the same exact controls on this iPhone screen as on iPad screen but with different orientation. Or should i separate that one screen into multiple UIViewControllers? Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is possible to answer. You need to design your user interface to match the target and, yes, that can mean starting pretty much from scratch when moving from iPhone to iPad (or vice versa).

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer:  You can do anything you want.

More elaborate:  You could do a scroll view like you mention, but I'm sure this would be sub-optimal.  You have a few options to deal with the difference in devices.  The one you choose usually depends on the view or the amount of content it contains.  You can 1) Simply resize it for the other device (this only works in rare situations where you have a simple view or one without much content).  2.  You create a separate view controller for each and launch the appropriate one for the device (per apple docs).  You could just slap your view in a scroll view, but depending on the specifics, a tab view, navigation controller, or some other option may provide a better user experience.  In the end it's up to you...

Comment: thanks. I have this idea. I dont know if it works. Can i have a View control (found in objects when we go to storyboard)onto which i can place a scrollview on iPhone storyboard and add all my 40-50 controls to scroll view and use that View on my iPhone screen?Can we do that?

Comment: I was trying to follow your point about using view in a scroll view..Can you elaborate more on that?

Comment: That approach is straight-forward, you simply add your views to a scroll view and the user can scroll up/down to see all of your components.  You'll have to be more specific if there's something you don't understand.